# Can an Iranian citizen enter the USA on a Dutch passport?

Tags: visas, usa, us-visa-waiver-program, iranian-citizens, dutch-citizens

I'm a Dutch citizen with a passport  and also an Iranian citizen. I would like to visit the USA. I have not been  in iran for 5 years. Can I enter the USA?

Comment: I thought the Netherlands didn't recognise dual nationality. So in case you are Iranian and became a Dutch citizen, you'd have ceased to be a citizen of Iran. I don't know in case you are Dutch and became a citizen of Iran, but I think your Dutch passport would no longer be valid. Or is this incorrect?

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ Netherlands does recognise dual nationality, but it's complicated. They want their citizens to have 1 nationality, so you have to lose the 'old' nationality upon becoming Dutch, but there are exceptions, like being born in Netherlands with multiple nationalities, or being Iranian before naturalization, two situations that could have applied to the question-asker. See: https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/nederlandse-nationaliteit/dubbele-nationaliteit and https://ind.nl/paginas/afstand-nationaliteit.aspx

Comment: @Belle-Sophie I see! Interesting, there is an exception for Greeks and Iranians, I didn't know that

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ there are countries that don't allow giving up their citizenship, like Morocco and indeed Iran. Hence the exceptions.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ People can lose their nationality automatically by naturalizing somewhere only if the law of the *old* nationality provides for that to happen.  The new country's law can only require people to renounce the old nationality as a requirement for naturalizing. The Netherlands has both rules, though both have exceptions. But it's also possible to be a dual national from birth, in which case none of this applies; the Netherlands does not prohibit that, though people in that situation can lose their Dutch nationality under certain circumstances.

Comment: @Belle-Sophie being born with multiple nationalities does not depend on the place of birth in Dutch law.  A child of a Dutch citizen born in Canada or the US, for example, is a dual national from birth (unless the parent has diplomatic immunity in the country of birth).  The child of an Iranian father and Dutch mother born in one of those countries would have three nationalities.

Comment: @phoog I know, my former boss always complains about having to do taxes in the US because he was born there. I just mentioned it as an example. Maybe I expressed myself poorly. My father was a Dutch/Belgian citizen because both he and his father were born in Netherlands, even though his father was just Belgian. So he got multiple nationalities because he was born there.

Answer (score 21):

In general, Dutch citizens are able to use the Visa Waiver Program (VWP) to enter the US, which would require obtaining an [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/) before travel.

However under the "[Visa Waiver Program Improvement and Terrorist Travel Prevention Act of 2015](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/visa-waiver-program/visa-waiver-program-improvement-and-terrorist-travel-prevention-act-faq)", the US added additional restrictions to the VWP program, and people that are nationals of Iran, Iraq, Sudan, or Syria are no longer eligible to enter the US under the VWP - regardless of any other citizenship they hold.

If you do apply for an ESTA, you will be required to state your additional citizenship, and as a result your ESTA will be denied.  Without an ESTA, you can not travel to the US using the VWP.

The only alternative that is available to you is to [apply for a US Visa](https://www.usa.gov/visas) at a US Consulate.  If a visa is approved, then you will be able to travel to the US.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can travel to the US with your Dutch passport.  You cannot use the visa waiver program, however, and therefore you should not apply for ESTA.  Instead, you need a visa.